Finding Type 2 and Type 3 Code Duplicates in ABAP Code
I want to reduce redundancy in my ABAP code to adhere to the DRY principle. To achieve this, I'm looking for a tool similar to CCFinderX that can identify Type 2 and Type 3 code duplicates.
**
Examples of duplicates:
Type 2 duplicates:
Z_PROGRAMM_1:
SELECT * FROM mara INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_materials) WHERE matnr = '12345'.
LOOP AT lt_materials INTO DATA(ls_material).
  WRITE: / ls_material-matnr, ls_material-maktx.
ENDLOOP.

Z_PROGRAMM_2:
SELECT * FROM mara INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_products) WHERE matnr = '67890'.
LOOP AT lt_products INTO DATA(ls_product).
  WRITE: / ls_product-matnr, ls_product-maktx.
ENDLOOP.

Type 3 duplicates:
Z_PROGRAMM_1:
SELECT * FROM mara INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_mara) WHERE matnr = '12345'.
LOOP AT lt_mara INTO DATA(ls_mara).
  WRITE: / ls_mara-matnr, ls_mara-maktx.
ENDLOOP.

Z_PROGRAMM_2:
SELECT * FROM mara INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_mara) WHERE matnr = '12345'.
LOOP AT lt_mara INTO DATA(ls_mara).
  IF ls_mara-mtart = 'FERT'.
    WRITE: / ls_mara-matnr, ls_mara-maktx.
  ELSE.
    WRITE: / 'Material type is not FERT'.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

I want to refactor these duplicates into a single class, but first, I need an efficient way to find them. Does the Code Inspector (SCI) or the ABAP Test Cockpit (ATC) have the capability to identify such duplicates? If not, are there any open-source tools available for detecting code duplicates in ABAP?
